# Why aren't my unit tests running in the project output folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nunit-3.0

I am having a problem that I have not experienced before.  When I run my nUnit unit tests the working folder is not the bin folder of the project.  If I run with Resharper it is a sub-folder of `AppData\Local\Jetbrains` and if I use the Visual Studio test runner it is a sub-folder of the Visual Studio 14 installation folder.
So where I have used `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and `Environment.CurrentDirectory` in previous solutions, they are no longer working.

I have turned off shadow copy in Resharper.

How do I get my unit tests to be run from the bin\debug folder so the system under test can find the files it needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Breaking Change](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Breaking-Changes) in NUnit 3. Use `TestContext.TestDirectory` to get the file the dll is built to.